# Why cannot change the colors KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am new on python and on kivyMD.

I am trying to change the colors of the project throw the them_cls function. However, the app shows the default colors even when I am changing the colors. For example, when I put Amber, green, or even Red, the buttons show the default blue color. This also happens with the general background of the app. When I put dark on the style theme color and run the app, it continues showing in white.

I don't know what to do. Here is the code

Phyton file:

```
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
 
 
class Ma(MDBoxLayout):
    pass
 
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def Build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Amber" #"Red" "Green"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return 0
    pass
 
MyApp().run()
```

Kivy file:

```
<Ma>:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Hello World"
        md_bc_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Hello World"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
```

Comment: Your screen is white because Python is case-sensitive and `def Build(self):` must be `def build(self)`  - lowercase **b**. And I think you have to define the available colors with a dictionary as mentioned in the docs [here](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes/theming/index.html)

Comment: @AWolf thanks!! that worked